# Introducing NA to as.numeric

Tags: r

I have this string variable

```
mystr <- "98,015"
```

and I want to convert it to number.

So I use:

```
num <- as.numeric(mystr)
```

but I receive this error:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

This introduce NA instead the number. If a use a string like `"21"` I take the number successfully. What can I do?

Comment: `readr::parse_number("98,015")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to replace the `,` with `""` and then convert it to `numeric`.  Because of the `,` character, applying the `as.numeric` coerces it to NA.

```
as.numeric(sub(",", "", mystr))
```

If `,` represent `.`, then replace it with `.` (Based on @RHertel's comments)

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", mystr))
```

---

It is not clear whether the OP's original dataset is a `data.frame` or just `vector`.  If it is a data.frame, while reading with `read.csv/read.table`, we can specify the `dec=","`.

Comment: Thank you. It works `as.numeric(sub(",", "", mystr))`! What should I do if I have a number like this "1,071,911"

Comment: @Jason_K  In that case you can use `gsub` instead of `sub` (but from your example I thought there is only a single "," per each number

Answer (score 0):

gsub function also does the same

```
mystr <- c("98,015","10,125","11,456")

mystr <- as.numeric(gsub("\\,","",mystr))

class(mystr)
 [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: you don't need to escape comma and what exactly is the difference with the other answer, except uselessly using `gsub` instead of `sub` ?

Comment: Thanks Cath for your update will try with other function