# deleting rows in R containing one blank column

Tags: r, dataframe, null, conditional-statements

I have a data set like:

```
  ID               EMAIL_ID.x        ID.y     EMAIL_ID.y
 60842               k@aol.com      60842        k@aol.com
 90853                a.b.c         NA            <NA>
 90854                b.c.d         NA            <NA>
 83907               h@gwi.net      02854         <NA>
 83908             s@hotmail.com    00952         <NA>
 83909             l@rediff.com     78895         <NA>
```

In this data, i only want to retain the rows in which both the 3rd and the 4th column are either populated or both not populated.

Hence the result should be like:

```
   ID               EMAIL_ID.x       ID.y     EMAIL_ID.y
 60842               k@aol.com      60842        k@aol.com
 90853                a.b.c         NA            <NA>
 90854                b.c.d         NA            <NA>
```

In the above, the rows where column 3 had values but column 4 did not, have been deleted.

Please suggest how can this be done in R.

Thankyou!

Comment: `df[rowSums(is.na(df[,3:4]))!=1,]`

Comment: assuming that all NAs are actual NAs and not strings as they are currently presented in the example

Comment: Trying the above gave me result like:

Comment: NA       <NA>         NA       <NA>      for all rows

Comment: You could try to use the `na.strings` parameter when reading the file. For example: `na.strings = c('NA','<NA>')`. Otherwise, please include the output of `dput(head(name_of_your_df)` in your question.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus  Sorry I think the dupe is not correct as the question is asking for a different logic `either populated or both not populated`.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus i.e. `either populated or both not populated`

Comment: which is still a rowwise NA count imo

Comment: @akrun well the answer is certainly the same or very very similar, which makes it a dupe

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus  The logic in that dupe is `d[rowSums(is.na(d[1:3]))<2,]` ie. less than 2 NAs, but here the logic is different

Comment: @akrun no, the numbers are different but the logic (row-wise counting of NAs) is exacly the same. Just a variation of the same thing.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus  Are you saying that all logic that use `rowSums` is a dupe.

Comment: @akrun no, see also Cath's comment

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus  All I am saying is the one that was closed [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490749/introducing-na-to-as-numeric) by RHertel is an exact dupe and not this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to check whether there are NA elements (`is.na(...)`) in both (`&`) columns or (`|`) both non-NA elements (by negating `!`) and use that logical index to subset the rows.

```
df1[is.na(df1[,3]) & is.na(df1[,4]) | !is.na(df1[,3]) & !is.na(df1[,4]),]
#    ID EMAIL_ID.x JPNUMBER.y EMAIL_ID.y
#1 60842  k@aol.com      60842  k@aol.com
#2 90853      a.b.c         NA       <NA>
#3 90854      b.c.d         NA       <NA>
```

---

Or another option is to apply `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`is.na(df1[3:4])`), check if the sum of NA elements are either 0 or 2 using `%in%` (if it is 0 - it implies there are no NA elements and 2 means both the columns have NA) and use the logical vector to subset the rows.

```
df1[rowSums(is.na(df1[3:4])) %in% c(0,2),]
#    ID EMAIL_ID.x JPNUMBER.y EMAIL_ID.y
#1 60842  k@aol.com      60842  k@aol.com
#2 90853      a.b.c         NA       <NA>
#3 90854      b.c.d         NA       <NA>
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `lapply` (to avoid conversion to matrix - in case the dataset is really big)

```
df1[Reduce(`+`, lapply(df1[3:4], is.na)) != 1,]
```

NOTE: If the NA in the OP's dataset is not real NA, we need to convert it to real NA before doing this (assuming the 4th column is `character` class)

```
is.na(df1[,4]) <- df1[,4] == "<NA>"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(60842L, 90853L, 90854L, 83907L, 83908L, 
83909L), EMAIL_ID.x = c("k@aol.com", "a.b.c", "b.c.d", "h@gwi.net", 
"s@hotmail.com", "l@rediff.com"), JPNUMBER.y = c(60842L, NA, 
NA, 2854L, 952L, 78895L), EMAIL_ID.y = c("k@aol.com", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "EMAIL_ID.x", "JPNUMBER.y", "EMAIL_ID.y"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```